# Record triggered flow not invoking when Event record is created via Lightning sync

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, automation, event, lightning-sync-configurations

**Issue:**

In our org events are created via lighting sync when outlook meeting is scheduled for user who is part of sync configuration.

- When a lead has events associated with it and that event owner is different from lead owner and when same event owner converts the lead then event owner gets updated to lead owner.
- This is standard Salesforce functionality and also mentioned in Salesforce article ([Events assigned to the User converting the Lead will be reassigned to the new owner, regardless of whether they are Open Activities or listed in Activity History](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385227&type=1) )

***We want to maintain original event owner after lead conversion.***

**Workaround used to maintain event owner after lead conversion:**

1. Created Checkbox field on Activity object which is by default FALSE.
2. When Event is created by sync and if it is associated with lead (i.e.
   `00Q`), through flow we are making checkbox field to TRUE.
3. When lead converts that event get associated to Household and Person Account
   (i.e. `WHOID` = Contact)
4. In Step 3, a flow invokes which check the
   condition that if Event checkbox field is TRUE and Event owner IS
   CHANGED ( it will change as per standard functionality) then as a
   action flow assign Prior Event owner on event and make checkbox
   field as FALSE.
5. This way we were able to maintain event owner after
   lead conversion.

**Issue with workaround:**

Since event is created via lighting sync, automation (flow/trigger) does not triggers on Event as per Salesforce support response. Hence our workaround is not functional due to flow is not getting invoked and we are unable to maintain event owner.

**Note:** When event is created manually in Salesforce, flow works and set checkbox field to TRUE.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: if no triggering action occurs on Lightning Sync of Events, a workaround would be to run a Schedule-triggered Flow to clean up these Event records after the fact (daily); or use an Apex Scheduled Job that could run every few minutes